# Can't click on element using webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am facing a very strange problem. I am trying to open facebook>click on forgotten account link> then opening it in a new tab> click on two textboxes.
My code is :

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;


public class OpenLinkInNewTabTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "<path>\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");
        String ParentWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
        WebElement w = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Forgotten account?"));


        new Actions(driver)
        .keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
        .keyDown(Keys.SHIFT)
        .click(w)
        .keyUp(Keys.SHIFT)
        .keyUp(Keys.CONTROL)
        .perform();

    new Actions(driver)
        .sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "w")
        .perform();




    // ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
//   
//  driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
//  WebElement fn = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 20))
//            .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#identify_email")));
//  System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
//  fn.sendKeys("abcdejf:");



    for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){

         driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
        if(driver.getTitle().contains("Forgotten Password ")){

            Thread.sleep(5000);


              driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#identify_email")).sendKeys("adf");
            driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("ASF");
            driver.close();
            driver.switchTo().window(ParentWindowHandle);

            break; 

        }
    }


    driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("ASF");

    }

}
```

However, I am unable to send value to

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#identify_email")).sendKeys("adf");
```

The element looks like:

```
<input id="identify_email" class="inputtext" name="email" autofocus="1" type="text">
```

If I write a similar code like:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","path\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");

        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Forgotten account?")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("ASF");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#identify_email")).sendKeys("adf");
```

It is able to click both the elements properly.
I am not seeing any element not found exception too while running it. Please help me to debug this issue.
Thanks.
UPDATE:

Running this code sometimes show

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: invalid element state
  (Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.87)
```

Comment: Are you getting an error or is the field simply staying empty?

Comment: I am not getting any error in console, and the field is staying empty too.

Comment: Selecting by name "email" yields two input fields. The form on the top of the page also has a field named like that. WebDriver will only return the first one using `findElement(By.name("email"))`. Your css selector should work, though. I suggest you try `By.id("identify_email")`

Comment: Tried before, no luck, then I tried css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait for this element:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
String email = "you@domain.com";
WebElement emailInputField = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#identify_email")));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', ' " + email + "')", emailInputField);
break;
```

Clicking activates this element.

Comment: The whole page is built from JS, so this might indeed help. On the other hand, WebDriver should throw an exception if the element cannot be found.

Comment: I have tried this with 20 sec as wait time as well, not working. Didn't get any exception either.

Comment: @Avishek2585835, I have edited my answer. This code should go into your if-block.

Comment: @Avishek2585835, a lot of JS on the Facebook site. Edited my answer another time. This time it should work.

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz Ya. this has worked. Switch to Javascript when nothing works. I forgot to try this while digging. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz  II am able to send values to the field, now I have another statement to execute on the same page, which was working before, driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#email")).sendKeys("ASF");Any help on this?

Comment: @Avishek2585835, I would try to do it without JavaScript. If it's impossble, then do it the same way I look for the element with class `identify_email` in my code. Instantiate string with the value you want to input, wait for the element and then execute JavaScript the way as in the answer.